# How to make website bigger on mobile with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

My website: [click](http://szybkieczytanie.gda.pl/)
How to make the website bigger on mobile phones? I would like to have bigger logo and other stuff. The zoom property is not working on iPhone, as I have this in my CSS:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        zoom: 150%;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man!  I don't think that's a good idea.  Are you perhaps looking for something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: Set the viewport as @JosephMarikle said, then unprefixed `transform:scale(1.5)` (or maybe `-webkit-transform`, depending how old systems you're targeting) should work.

Answer (score 12):

Zooming your website is a bad idea. Try adding this to your `<head>` and read more about the `viewport` meta tag on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Answer (score -1):

first set your viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=0.75, maximum-scale=3.0" />
```

the write zoom like

```
zoom: 1.8;
```